# Capturing data between specific tag in python

Tags: python, find

I am getting url content in python... I want to capture everything between `<h1>` and `</h1>`.

What I tried is:

```
myString='''<h1>kgkgjgjgkjgkjgkj</h1>
<h1>kdfgggggggggggggggggggkgjgjgkjgkjgkj</h1>
dsfgdfgg
<h1>kgkgjgjgkdfgdfgdgdfjgkjgkj</h1>
dfgdffdgf
<h1>kgkgjgjsdssssssssssssssssssssgkjgkjgkj</h1>
dfgdfgdg
<h1>kgkgjgjgkjgkjgkgggggggggggggggggggj</h1>
'''
if '<h1>' in myString:
    startString='<h1>'
    endString='</h1>'
    print myString[myString.find(startString)+len(startString):myString.find(endString)]
```

I have multiple `h1` tags. but it capture data between the first h1 tag.

How can I capture data between all `h1` tags?

Comment: Please share the sample data with those multiple `h1` tags as well.

Comment: You should use [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) if you intend to extract html content, its much easier.

Comment: Why on earth, after presenting [a regex attempt at this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33462382/3001761) and being told you should use an HTML parser, have you tried to implement it yourself with string searching?! If you want to parse HTML, *use an HTML parser* - the clue's right there in the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for Beautifulsoup-- my attempt

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'http://accessibility.psu.edu/headingshtml/'

respons = requests.get(url).content

soup = BeautifulSoup(respons,'lxml')

h1tags = soup.find_all('h1')

for singleTag in h1tags:
    print singleTag.text
```

Prints ( in this case only one h1 tag)

```
Heading Tags (H1, H2, H3, P) in HTML
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using a simple [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

```
import re
print re.findall(r'<h1>(.*?)</h1>', myString)
```

Another way is to use Beautiful Soup as an HTML parser (which is more preferred way if you want to parse real world HTML pages):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(myString)
print [h1.string for h1 in soup.find_all('h1')]
```

[BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is not included into standard library, so you will need to install it manually. You can easily install it via pip:

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

Answer (score 1):

Use BeautifulSoup parser.

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> myString='''<h1>kgkgjgjgkjgkjgkj</h1>
<h1>kdfgggggggggggggggggggkgjgjgkjgkjgkj</h1>
dsfgdfgg
<h1>kgkgjgjgkdfgdfgdgdfjgkjgkj</h1>
dfgdffdgf
<h1>kgkgjgjsdssssssssssssssssssssgkjgkjgkj</h1>
dfgdfgdg
<h1>kgkgjgjgkjgkjgkgggggggggggggggggggj</h1>
'''
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(myString)
>>> h1 = soup.select('h1')
>>> for i in h1:
    print i.text


kgkgjgjgkjgkjgkj
kdfgggggggggggggggggggkgjgjgkjgkjgkj
kgkgjgjgkdfgdfgdgdfjgkjgkj
kgkgjgjsdssssssssssssssssssssgkjgkjgkj
kgkgjgjgkjgkjgkgggggggggggggggggggj
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you. How can I get rid of Error: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bs4/__init__.py:166: UserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("lxml"). This usually isn't a problem, but if you run this code on another system, or in a different virtual environment, it may use a different parser and behave differently. To get rid of this warning, change this: BeautifulSoup([your markup]) to this: BeautifulSoup([your markup], "lxml") markup_type=markup_type))

Comment: @MortezaLSC again, **that's not an error**. Did you consider *reading it?!*

Comment: try `soup = BeautifulSoup(myString, "html.parser")`

Comment: @AvinashRaj `soup.select` is a smart way alternative of `find_all` hehe!

Answer (score 0):

Working example with Beautiful Soup

```
>>> import bs4
>>> myString='''<h1>kgkgjgjgkjgkjgkj</h1>
... <h1>kdfgggggggggggggggggggkgjgjgkjgkjgkj</h1>
... dsfgdfgg
... <h1>kgkgjgjgkdfgdfgdgdfjgkjgkj</h1>
... dfgdffdgf
... <h1>kgkgjgjsdssssssssssssssssssssgkjgkjgkj</h1>
... dfgdfgdg
... <h1>kgkgjgjgkjgkjgkgggggggggggggggggggj</h1>
... '''
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(myString)
>>> soup.find("h1").text
u'kgkgjgjgkjgkjgkj'
>>> soup.find_all("h1")
[<h1>kgkgjgjgkjgkjgkj</h1>, <h1>kdfgggggggggggggggggggkgjgjgkjgkjgkj</h1>, <h1>kgkgjgjgkdfgdfgdgdfjgkjgkj</h1>, <h1>kgkgjgjsdssssssssssssssssssssgkjgkjgkj</h1>, <h1>kgkgjgjgkjgkjgkgggggggggggggggggggj</h1>]
```

Comment: Error:` /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bs4/__init__.py:166: UserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("lxml"). This usually isn't a problem, but if you run this code on another system, or in a different virtual environment, it may use a different parser and behave differently.

To get rid of this warning, change this:

 BeautifulSoup([your markup])

to this:

 BeautifulSoup([your markup], "lxml")

  markup_type=markup_type))`

Comment: @MortezaLSC so did you read that message, and/or do what it suggested?

Comment: Ah! it will not return all h1 tags but one of them.:(

Comment: @SIslam both methods are shown, find will only return the first occurence while find_all will return all of the elements searched for.

Comment: Thanks- i assumed as per OP's need - no need of `find`, anyway thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simple list comp solution:

```
print [s.split('</h1>')[0] for s in myString.split('<h1>')[1:]]
```